# Rails Form multi-select list keyboard keys+display type and subtype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form for `@product` that does multi-select list of product types(stored in database with has-many-through association between product-type.It works correctly by putting correct values in DB.

```
    <%= f.collection_select(:type_ids, Type.all.order(:name), :id, :name,
    {:selected => @product.type_ids, include_blank: false,:required => true},
    {:multiple => true, size: 5})%>
```

But I have 2 issues:

1. I'm unable to use `ctrl+click` key for multi select. Only `shift+click` works. Any other method other than this or do I need to enable some keyboard/browser for `Macbook Pro-version 10.12.2 & Chrome`?
2. I have in the DB a column `subtype(brand)` for product. I want to display in the above a multi-select box showing both `ptype and subtype columns from DB` table Type as following: (I guess it's by grouped_options_for_select but can't find relevant example of retrieving from DB.)

> Clothes -- M&S 
>  Clothes -- Next 
>  Clothes -- Monsoon

Comment: Take a look at https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thx. It's just as I had wanted.I cannot mark as 'answer' as it's a comment but +1.

Answer (score 0):

so [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) is what you are looking for :)